# How to readline to find a match string and split the result into multiple files

Tags: python, readline, strip

This is the scenario, I've a pattern file that I needed to read line by line.

The content of the pattern file somewhat similar to this

```
chicken 
chicken
chicken
chicken
## comment
## comment
fish
fish
chicken
chicken
chicken
```

The code I've came up so far is like this.

```
def readlines_write():
    with open(filename) as rl:
        for line in rl:
            if "chicken" in line:
                with open(new_filename, 'a+') as new_rl:
                    new_rl.write(line)
```

With above code I can find all "chicken" in that pattern file and the result would be write in new_filename. But that is not the objective. Because I've lump sum it all together in one file.

I would like to split the chicken and write it to multiple files.

Eg. In the end result should be, read line by line continuously, if found chicken and stop when the next line is not contain chicken. Break and write it to a file, a.out for example.

And the script continue read line by line and found the next matches after the "comment" and "fish". And write the result to b.out

I've the pseudo in mind but I'm not sure how to translate it to python logic.

Summary, I would like to split the chicken that got separated by the comment and other words than chicken.

Comment: You want 2 files, one that contains lines of chicken and one that contains lines of everything else?

Comment: Nope. I want to the file name to be in increment. Whenever the chicken is being split by comment or other line that do not contain chicken. The next line of chicken should reside on a new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an else condition and keep changing the name of the file by an integer or timestamp.

```
def readlines_write():
        i = 0
        new_filename = 'filename{}.out'.format(i)
        with open(filename) as rl:
            for line in rl:
                if "chicken" in line:
                    with open(new_filename, 'a+') as new_rl:
                        new_rl.write(line)
                else:
                    i +=1
                    new_filename = 'filename{}.out'.format(i)
```

Comment: Thanks man. This is what I looking for. Anyway why the filename seems like it was random?

Comment: @IzzatZainol Thanks! You can replace the 'filename' with whatever name you would like.

Answer (score 2):

So, what you're looking for is *contiguous groups* of `chicken` lines, and you want to put each group into it a separate file. Fine, [batteries are included](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
import itertools

def is_chicken(x):
    return 'chicken' in x # Can add more complex logic.

def write_groups(input_sequence):
    count = 1
    grouper = itertools.groupby(input_sequence, is_chicken)
    for found, group in grouper:
        # The value of `found` here is what `is_chicken` returned;
        # we only want groups where it returned true.
        if found:
            with open('file-%d.chicken' % count, 'w') as f:
                f.writelines(group)
            count += 1
```

Now you can

```
with open('input_file') as input_file:
    write_groups(input_file)
```

The same thing can be done in a more functionally-decomposed way, though a bit harder to understand in you're not used to generators:

```
def get_groups(input_sequence):
    grouper = itertools.groupby(input_sequence, is_chicken)
    # Return a generator producing only the groups we want.
    return (group for (found, group) in grouper if found)


with open('input_file') as input_file:
    for (count, group) in enumerate(get_groups(input_file), start=1):
        with open('file-%d.chicken' % count, 'w') as f:
            f.writelines(group)
```

Comment: Wow this way too advance. This is ninja coding. Thank you for the answer.